# How can I find the radius of a circle from a chord and a section of the radius?

Tags: geometry, circles

Draw a circle with center *O*.

Line *AD* is a chord that is 8cm long. The arc above is smaller than the one below.

*B* is the center of *AD*.

Line *CB* is a line that is 2cm long. It meets *AD* at 90°.

Diagram:

[image]

Given the facts above, is it possible to find *CO* (the radius of the circle)? If so, what is the radius, and how can I find it for any other circle?

Comment: I wondered what was meant by "The segment above is smaller than the one below."  After a while it occurred to me that you meant "The arc above is smaller than the one below."  That is standard terminology and everyone would understand it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've been taught that the area between the arc and the chord is the segment... Is arc better?

Comment: I may be that some geometry texts use that terminology.  To me the word "segment" normally means a line segment.

Comment: @Michael Okay, will bear that in mind! Maybe UK vs US teaching?

Comment: It’s standard stuff to find the center from three points $(P,Q,R)$ on the circumference. The perpendicular bisectors of $PQ$ and $PR$ meet at the center. You could turn turn that into an algebraic treatment, I suppose. This can not be the easiest method, I’m sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $OB=x$, then $OA=OC=x+2$. Now apply Pythagoras theorem in triangle $AOB$

Answer (score 8):

Let $CO=r$ then we have $r^2=(r-2)^2+4^2$. Solve for $r=5$

Comment: Is the 4 half of AD? And why does that work?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it is.

Comment: Are there any specific theorems that I can refer to to explain why this works?

Comment: Ahh got it - pythagoras!

Comment: @Tim What you need to know is $OA=OD$, hence the angle $OBA$ is a right angle. Then by Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: It also helps to realize that OA = OD = OC, which are all the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Because $D$ lies on the circle, $OD^2=OB^2+BD^2$. Also because $OD(=OC)=OB+BC$, $OB=OD-BC$. Substituting $OB$ in the first equation yields

$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $OD^2=(OD-BC)^2+BD^2$
$≡$ $OD^2= OD^2-2\centerdot OD\centerdot BC+ BC^2+BD^2$
$≡$ $2\centerdot OD\centerdot BC =BC^2+BD^2$
$≡$ $OD = (BC^2 + BD^2)/(2\centerdot BC)$

For the example at hand, this results in a radius of $(2^2+4^2)/(2\centerdot 2) = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\overline{CC^\prime}$ be a diameter.

By Power of a Point, $AB \cdot BD = CB \cdot BC^\prime = 4 \cdot 4 = 2 \cdot BC^\prime$.

Then $BC^\prime = 8$, $CC^\prime = 10$, and $CO = 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Edited your sketch. When two line segments cut at B, use circle segments property of constant products:

$ BA . BD = BC. BE ; 2 ( 2 R -2) = 4^2 $  so $  R = 5. $

[image: CircleSegmentsCutting]